# How to stop Sidetiq adding schedule job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidetiq

I am using **Sidetiq** (https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) for schedule a frequent recurring job (every minute).

When I am testing in my local environment, even when I stop Sidekiq from executing, Sidetiq keeps adding new jobs to the scheduled jobs.

I try to get the Sidetiq pid by

```
ps -A | grep sidetiq
```

But every time I get a different PID back. Not sure I should kill it.

The only way for me to stop this now is to restart my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `kill -USR1 PID`.

See more information here https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals